# Asking for clarification - "in relation to"?

Tags: conversation

I wonder what would be the right phrase to use, once you encounter someone else's statement, which you can't see what it has to do with the conversation.

For example:

> **Jake**: I think he will win the next election!
>
> **Dan**: Well, a bird in the hand is worth two in the bush.

Which of the following is considered to be valid and natural:

1. What was that in relation to?
2. How is it related to our topic?
3. What it has to do with what I said?

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any of those would be possible and appropriate. The last should be "What does that have to do with what I said?"

Asking "How are 'birds in the bush' and elections connected?" is not a figure of speech, but it is a natural piece of sentence building, and so is appropriate and understandable.

There is one figure of speech "What does that have to do with the price of fish?"  or "[What does that have to do with the price of tea in China?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What%27s_that_got_to_do_with_the...%3F)", which is an ironic and facetious question. In most situations you would be better using simple expressions like yours: "How is that related?"

Comment: I've looked up the link you have posted from Wikipedia and saw this remark: _A related expression in Hebrew can be found in a commentary on the Biblical commandment... Rashi's commentary begins with the question "What is the connection between Shmita and Mount Sinai?" The question has since taken on a general meaning equivalent to that of the "price of tea in China" expression._ Now I wonder if **What is the connection between ... and ...** is a common figure of speech, and if it's not, will it be obvious to the listener what I'm asking?

Comment: @SunnySideDown That may have been a common figure of speech in Hebrew at the time of the writing of the Talmud I don't think it is in current English.